# Align list items center on mobile in bootstrap 4 with flex

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, anchor

I have a div, called header_full_width. This is a 100% width div on my page top. In this div, there is a container, a row, a col-md-12 div, and then an ul with list items and links.

My problem is, that on mobile, these links arent centered, they are going out of the page and the hortizontal scrollbar shows up.

I tried these classes: align-items-center and another html code, but it didnt worked.

```
<div class="header_full_width">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="header_links_ul header_links_ul_left d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-start">
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/" class="header_top_links" title="Kezdőlap">Kezdőlap</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/informaciok" class="header_top_links" title="Információk">Információk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/aktualis-akciok" class="header_top_links" title="Aktuális akciók">Aktuális akciók</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/kiemelt-termekek" class="header_top_links" title="Kiemelt termékek">Kiemelt termékek</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/hirek" class="header_top_links" title="Hírek, érdekességek">Hírek, érdekességek</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/elerhetosegek" class="header_top_links" title="Elérhetőségek">Elérhetőségek</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On mobile, i want these links vertically and horizontally centered, under each other.

[image: On full HD monitor]

[image: And on mobile screen]

Link to the demo website: [kemenyem.hu](https://kemenyem.hu)

Comment: Please share the css codes too

Comment: I dont have any css, just these bootstrap 4 classes.

Comment: i checked that code, which is showing as vertical. check the style of li as display:block;

Comment: Link to the site: kemenyem.hu

Comment: The problem is with d-flex class in <ul>
please add style for this ul

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
 ul.header_links_ul{
    display: block !important;
 }
 //Then for li class (for centering)
 ul.header_links_ul li{
    text-align:center
 }


}

Comment: there is no need to use own `css` like @WordpressDev said. take a look at my answer below. :)

Answer (score 0):

> The Problem is, that you are setting `d-flex` to all mediasizes.

- set `d-flex` to mediasizes over `xs` (mobile) using `d-sm-flex`
- set the `ul` to `d-inline-block` on `xs` using `d-xs-inline-block`

Now it should behave like you want to:

```
<div class="header_full_width">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <ul class="header_links_ul header_links_ul_left d-sm-flex d-xs-inline-block justify-content-md-start">
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/" class="header_top_links" title="Kezdőlap">Kezdőlap</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/informaciok" class="header_top_links" title="Információk">Információk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/aktualis-akciok" class="header_top_links" title="Aktuális akciók">Aktuális akciók</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/kiemelt-termekek" class="header_top_links" title="Kiemelt termékek">Kiemelt termékek</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/hirek" class="header_top_links" title="Hírek, érdekességek">Hírek, érdekességek</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/elerhetosegek" class="header_top_links" title="Elérhetőségek">Elérhetőségek</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

- *use `d-xs-inline-block` and `d-md-flex` instead, if you want it to be centered on `sm`, too*

> to learn more take a look at bootstraps documenations for [**display utility classes**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/) and [**responsive breakpoints**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [flex-column](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#direction), try this...

```
<ul class="header_links_ul header_links_ul_left d-flex justify-content-center flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center justify-content-md-start">
```